# Any performance improvement when passing variables than the whole object from HTML to Javascript in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, for-loop

I can either pass the iterating object as a whole from HTML to Javascript as shown below

```
<!-- HTML --!>
(click)="onChange(item)"
/* js */
onChange(item) {
getDetails(item.id, item.date, item.count)
}
```

or I can pass the only required properties of the iterating object as shown below

```
<!-- HTML --!>
(click)="onChange(item.id, item,date, item.count)"
/* js */
onChange(id, date, count) {
this.getDetails(id, date, count)
}
```

Consider the iterating item is having around 15 properties

```
item = {
id:"01",
date: "12/12/2017",
count:"1000",
name:"John Doe",
email:"john@doe.com"
...
...
... // goes on 

}
```

I just want to know which of the above approach gives better performance, passing the properties or the whole object ? I believe , I just want to pass the properties only. Anyway the code is running faster in both ways. But if some could explain the real difference, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think javascript engines like v8 store their object properties in hash map which makes it o(1), therefore if you pass the object and access the properties from inside the function it would not make any difference, however if you iterate over it, it would be slower

Comment: just out of curiousity, why would it be slower? If its `call by sharing` (for objects) and what gets passed is direct reference, what's the difference iterating it inside or outside the function? Or your point is that iterating in general is slower than accessing properties directly, separate from the passing problem? (which is true, of course)

Comment: I think he is not iterating outside he is passing references to properties and object and asking which would be faster

Comment: yes yes, but you introduced iterating case so i was just curious about that. (i'm aware its an offtopic, strictly speaking)

Comment: It does not matter where you iterate, its gonna be same all the time as long as you have reference to that object I think

Comment: yes, that's correct. ok, so you're saying that, in general, direct properties access is faster than iteration?

Comment: I think so. If you are iterating over something and doing if and else to check if it matches, it would be slower than direct memory access..

Comment: yes yes, you're right. just wanted to clarify the reasons. upvoted.